# Visual Studio C++ code gets a redefinition error

Tags: c++, uwp

After a system crash, I reinstalled VS and brought up my solution.  Now it gets a redefinition error in Microsoft code.  Example output below:

```
2>Compressor.xaml.cpp
....
2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt\windows.foundation.numerics.h(349): warning C4099: 'Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Rational': type name first seen using 'class' now seen using 'struct' (compiling source file Compressor.xaml.cpp)
2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt\windows.foundation.numerics.h(567): error C2371: 'ABI::Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Rational': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file Compressor.xaml.cpp)
2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt\windows.foundation.numerics.h(349): note: see declaration of 'ABI::Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Rational' (compiling source file Compressor.xaml.cpp)
2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt\windows.foundation.numerics.h(349): warning C4099: 'Windows::Foundation::Numerics::Rational': type name first seen using 'class' now seen using 'struct' (compiling source file CommonToolBar.xaml.cpp)
```

FYI: I don't use rational in my code.

The project is dead until this is fixed.  Ideas?

Comment: This happened after a clean rebuild?

Comment: Try manually delete all output binary files (*.obj, *.exe), hidden .vs directory and solution .db files. This can help.

Comment: This happens after a "Clean" and "Rebuild".  I have tried for over a day to get this to work.

Comment: I put the target back a few revisions and it worked.  Not a great solution.